# filter paganation results then update ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, pagination

ok, i have been working on this real estate page and we have pagination working now we want to be able to sort the categories.. all of which we can do BUT the pagination is not updating any one have any ideas here is my relevant code

```
controllers.js

    listingControllers.controller('todoCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.filteredTodos = [];
  $scope.itemsPerPage = 10;
  $scope.currentPage = 1;

  $scope.makeTodos = function() {
    $http.get('properties/master.json')
       .then(function(res){
            $scope.todos = res.data;
            $scope.figureOutTodosToDisplay();         
        });
  };
    $scope.figureOutTodosToDisplay = function() {
        var begin = (($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.itemsPerPage);
        var end = begin + $scope.itemsPerPage;
        $scope.filteredTodos = $scope.todos.slice(begin, end);
    };

    $scope.makeTodos(); 

    $scope.pageChanged = function() {
        $scope.figureOutTodosToDisplay();
    };
    $scope.$watch('search.renttype', function(term) {
        console.log('filter by ' + term);
        $scope.makeTodos();
        var temp = $scope.todos;
        $scope.filteredTodos = [];
        // Create $scope.filtered and then calculat $scope.noOfPages, no racing!

        $scope.todos = [];
        //console.log('filtered list?? ' + JSON.stringify(bob));
        $scope.todos = $.grep(temp, function(e){ 
             return e.xsitype == term; 
        });
        $scope.pageChanged();
    });
});
```

and my html

```
    <div class="container-fluid" ng-controller="todoCtrl">

    <section id="filters">
        <h2>Filters</h2>

    <fieldset>
        Realestate type:<br>
    ApartmentBuy          <input type="checkbox"  data-ng-model="search.renttype" data-ng-change="filterRealType()"  ng-true-value="'OfferApartmentBuy'" ng-false-value="" /><br>
    ApartmentRent         <input type="checkbox"  data-ng-model="search.renttype" data-ng-change="filterRealType()"  ng-true-value="'OfferApartmentRent'" ng-false-value="" /><br>
    HouseBuy              <input type="checkbox"  data-ng-model="search.renttype" data-ng-change="filterRealType()"  ng-true-value="'OfferHouseBuy'" ng-false-value="" /><br>
    HouseRent             <input type="checkbox"  data-ng-model="search.renttype" data-ng-change="filterRealType()"  ng-true-value="'OfferHouseRent'" ng-false-value="" /><br>
    Industry              <input type="checkbox"  data-ng-model="search.renttype" data-ng-change="filterRealType()"  ng-true-value="'OfferIndustry'" ng-false-value="" /><br>
    Office                <input type="checkbox"  data-ng-model="search.renttype" data-ng-change="filterRealType()"  ng-true-value="'OfferOffice'" ng-false-value="" /><br>
    Store                 <input type="checkbox"  data-ng-model="search.renttype" data-ng-change="filterRealType()"  ng-true-value="'OfferStore'" ng-false-value="" /><br>
    ShortTermAccommodation<input type="checkbox"  data-ng-model="search.renttype" data-ng-change="filterRealType()"  ng-true-value="'OfferShortTermAccommodation'" ng-false-value="" /><br>
    SpecialPurpose        <input type="checkbox"  data-ng-model="search.renttype" data-ng-change="filterRealType()"  ng-true-value="'OfferSpecialPurpose'" ng-false-value="" /><br>
    Gastronomy            <input type="checkbox"  data-ng-model="search.renttype" data-ng-change="filterRealType()"  ng-true-value="'OfferGastronomy'" ng-false-value="" /><br>
        </fieldset>

    </section>
    <h1 class="text-h3">Properties</h1>

    <div class="row gridalicious" data-toggle="gridalicious" data-width="200">

        <div class="galcolumn" ng-repeat="todo in filteredTodos | cartypefilter:search" " id="item0GLe5r" style="width: 19.7354497354497%; padding-left: 15px; padding-bottom: 15px; float: left; box-sizing: border-box; height: 395px;">

            <div class="panel panel-default relative">
                <div class="ribbon-heading ribbon-default inline absolute left margin-none"> {{ todo.xsitype }} </div>
                <div class="cover hover overlay margin-none" >
                    <img ng-src="{{ todo.titlePicture.urls[0].url[1].href }}" alt="location" class="img-responsive" />
                    <a href="#/listing/{{todo.id}}" class="overlay overlay-full overlay-bg-black overlay-hover">
                        <span class="v-center">
                            <span class="btn btn-circle btn-white"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></span>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <h4 class="margin-v-0-5">{{ todo.title  }}</h4>

                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                    <span class="label label-grey-100">&euro;{{ todo.price.value }}</span>&nbsp;

                    <a{% if angular %} ui-sref="{{ todo.externalId }}"{% else %} href="{{ todo.externalId}}"{% endif %} class="btn btn-primary btn-circle absolute bottom right"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <pagination boundary-links="true" 
    max-size="10" 
    items-per-page="itemsPerPage"
    total-items="todos.length" 
    ng-model="currentPage" 
    ng-change="pageChanged()"></pagination>
</div>
```

im sure i made a stupid mistake and we are using the bootstrap ui for pagination

Answer (score 0):

i figured this out actually and this is what i got

```
listingControllers.controller('todoCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $filter) {
$scope.todos = [];
$scope.filteredtodos = [];
$scope.currentPage = 1;
$scope.totallistings = 0;
$scope.pageSize = 10;
$scope.maxSize = 10;
$scope.lastfilter = null;


$scope.makeTodos = function() {
    $http.get('properties/master.json',{cache:true}).then(function(res){
        $scope.filteredtodos = null;
        $scope.filteredtodos = res.data;
        $scope.todos = res.data;
        //console.log('make todos');

    });
};
$scope.makeTodos(); 

//console.log('totalpages '+Math.ceil($scope.filteredtodos.length/$scope.pageSize)+'');
$scope.totalPages = Math.ceil($scope.filteredtodos.length/$scope.pageSize);
$scope.totallistings = $scope.filteredtodos.length;

$scope.$watch('search.renttype', function (newCityName) {

    $scope.currentPage = 1;

    if( typeof newCityName == "undefined" ) 
    {
        $scope.filteredtodos = null;
        $scope.filteredtodos = $scope.todos;
    }
    //console.log('last f+ '+$scope.lastfilter+' - '+newCityName+'');
    if ($scope.lastfilter != null && newCityName != $scope.lastfilter)
    {
        //console.log('filtercomp '+$scope.lastfilter+' - '+newCityName+'');
        $scope.filteredtodos = null;
        $scope.filteredtodos = $scope.todos;
    }
    $scope.lastfilter = newCityName;
    //console.log('filtere '+newCityName+' active');

    $scope.filteredtodos = $filter('filter')($scope.filteredtodos, {xsitype : newCityName});
    $scope.totallistings = $scope.filteredtodos.length;
    //console.log('totalpages filter '+Math.ceil($scope.filteredtodos.length/$scope.pageSize)+' tlist '+$scope.totallistings);
    $scope.totalPages = Math.ceil($scope.filteredtodos.length/$scope.pageSize);

});
```

});